# how to convert the result of product to hex?

Tags: python

how to use a method to change it into hexadecimal. It looks i made an mistake. please help me to find a solution.

```
print("Full Names:" " "+ string, [ord(i) for i in string])
product = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, [ord(i) for i in string])
print(product)
random.seed(2)
random.uniform(len(string) ,2000000)
product = reduce(lambda x,y: x^y, [ord(i) for i in string])
print(product)

         print("the exa number of:" + hex(54))
```

Comment: `print("the exa number of:" + hex(product))` ???

Comment: can you help me with this, Trim (cut the extra characters), your resulting number into 16 characters only

Comment: `print("the exa number of: " + hex(product)[0:16])`

Answer (score 0):

Printing in different bases can be done in a few ways:

First of all there is the `hex()` function:

```py
>>> print("The result is: ", hex(28))
The result is: 0x1c
```

This returns the hex as most other applications would want it.
However, if you only want the hex itself, without the `0x` to start it, you can use format(). This function has two variations, one with caps, and one with small letters, by passing it a small or a capital letter x respectively:

```
>>> print("The result is: ", format(28, "x")
The result is 1c
>>> print("The result is: ", format(28, "X"))
The result is 1C
```

Lastly, you can use `numpy` with `np.base_repr()`, which can print to any base, not just hexadecimal, but using that in this case would be overkill.

---

Once you have your string (e.g. from `format()`) you can do normal string operations on it if you want only a part of it. So, getting the first 16 characters would be:

```py
print("The result is: "format(28, "x")[:16])
```

I hope that helps! :-)

Comment: random.seed(2)
result=random.uniform(len(string), 2000000)
print("Random number:", int(result))
b = int(product) ^ int(result)
print( "XOR:", b)
print(result)
print("Hexa:",hex(product))
print("Hash:",hex(product)[0:16])
    There is an error with XOR could u please help me